# How safe is it to use login data within a PHP session?

Tags: php, codeigniter

For example, how safe would it be to do the following to log in the user: (`set_userdata` just sets the `$_SESSION` variable).

```
$sess_array = array(
     'id' => $row->id,
     'username' => $row->username
   );
   $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
```

(from http://www.iluv2code.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html)

And to check whether that array has a valid ID and username on every page, to make sure the user is logged in? Does keeping the ID make it safer (if a regular user cannot find this ID)?

Comment: I personally avoid using the username in a session, because it is possible to sniff the session variables.  If you wanted more secure, you could create a new random hash when they log in, store it in the user db record and in the session, then compare THAT each page load.  Then you have virtually no leakage of information, and it would be much harder to spoof a nice SHA1 hash than to guess / spoof an ID and username.

Comment: Doesn't codeigniter come with it's own login library? Why are you rolling your own?

Comment: There is no standard one and I'm not afraid of making one on my own. I've made database sessions before, but I was mostly wondering about the safety of this code used in the tutorial.

Comment: @cale_b If it is possible to sniff the session variables: why is a hash better than a username?

Comment: Yes, but that information is pseudo-random garbage, and wouldn't be leakage of real information (such as username or userid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the users name might make your application vulnerable to brute force attacks if the session is sniffed and the user name retrieved.

So you want to create a loggedIN token that is then stored in the session and the DB and compared when content that requires login is called.

Tokens should be indexed unique and regularly destroyed users not logged in have NULL. This keeps temp tables leaner when tokens are compared upon loading content.

Answer (score 1):

PHP sessions are stored on the **server**, means no client can read / manipulate it from the outside (except you'd allow it through a http request or similar): **so you should be safe**.

However, if you are storing the user's name don't forget to escape it when running it through a SQL-Query.

Keeping the ID does not make it safer but more convenient:

- No escaping needed (besides casting)
- Easier / faster lookup in the database (compare an integer lookup to a string lookup)
- An ID is **unique** (unambiguous) compared to a user's name.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer! Can you elaborate on this: `except you'd allow it through a http request or similar` please?

Comment: As said, sessions are stored on the server. But this does not necessarily mean that you are safe: if you are **letting** (accidentally or not) the client write or read their own sessions then you will have a problem. This won't happen of course if you are paying attention on **how and when** you are writing sessions.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to hijack PHP Session without server access. However It's possible to do a [Timing attack](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2014/May/54) using the cookie, which is accessible for the user. So I recommend encrypt your cookie to make it more secure.

Set this in your `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']  = 9600;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;
```